# Start-Process : Process with an Id of 5344 is not running

Tags: powershell

```
PS C:\> start regedit -ArgumentList '/S', 'D:\resources\hawk_config.reg' -Wait
Start-Process : Process with an Id of 5344 is not running.
At line:1 char:6
+ start <<<<  regedit -ArgumentList '/S', 'D:\resources\hawk_config.reg'
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Start-Process], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

I can't figure out what it is. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you try `start-process` instead?

Comment: `start` is an alias for `start-process`

Comment: I figured, but I thought it was worth a try. How about using `"` instead of `'`?

Comment: In this case `'` would be the same as `"`. You only need to use double quotes if you need to use variable substitution, ie: `"Arguments are: $Args"`. For single quotes you can use format: `'Arguments are: {0}' -f $Args`

Comment: I haven't used PS before, so I'm stabbing in the dark. Sorry for wasting your time, but could you try using `-ArgumentList` as the last switch? And/or even something like `-ArgumentList @('/S', 'D:\resources\hawk_config.reg')`?

Comment: Sadly, I tried putting `-ArgumentList` as the last switch, and tried changing the switch string up many ways, but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't the `/S` parameter cause regedit to exit as soon as it's merged the .reg file?  I suspect the error you are getting is because regedit has already exited before Start-Process has a chance to call Process.WaitForExit() on the process object.  Take a look at the bowels of the error by running `$error[0] | Format-List *` right after the command.  `WaitForExit()` will throw a `SystemException` if the process has already exited.  I can't repro this on PowerShell v3.  Perhaps they fixed an issue with this cmdlet.

As a workaround you could try:

```
$p = start-process regedit -ArgumentList '/S', 'D:\resources\hawk_config.reg' -passthru
$p.WaitForExit()
```

Answer (score 0):

*WaitForExit() will throw a SystemException if the process has already exited.*

I get this same thing randomly in a PS script that uses start-process in a loop. never on the same iteration, sometimes never at all. this would explain that behavior perfectly. Random asynchronous timing of threads and processes.

I tried the suggested error message dump and it looks like it confirms the idea that the process is finishing before WaitForExit() gets to see it:

> Start-Process : Cannot process request because the process (38152) has exited.
>
> $result = start-process <<<<  -filepath $compiler -argumentlist $argstr -nonewwindow -passthru -wait
>   CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand